# How to modify $content_for_layout in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, layout, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I am using CakePHP 1.3. In `app/views/layouts/default.ctp` I am using this:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
```

According to CakePHP Application Development, by Ahsanul Bari and Anupom Syam,

> "This line is mainly responsible for placing controller-rendered view
>   contents inside the layout. We must include this to tell Cake where to
>   place the action-specific controller-rendered views."

I was trying to figure out how to modify the content of `$content_for_layout`. But I guess that is not the kind of variable that I am supposed to modify to modify the layout. What I am trying to accomplish is to either modify `$content_for_layout` or create a new layout to customize some elements for an A/B testing experiment. Could you help me to better understand how to manipulate `$content_for_layout`? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I am configuring an A/B testing experiment. I have this in `app/views/layouts/default.ctp`:

```
<body>
    ..........
    <div id="split-test-homepage-content-original">
        ..........
        <?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
        ..........
    </div>
    <div id="split-test-homepage-content-redesign">
        ..........
        <?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
        ..........
    </div/>
</body>
```

With CSS I am hiding/showing either `split-test-homepage-content-original` or `split-test-homepage-content-redesign` depending on the version that the split test will show. But I am having problems because `$content_for_layout` is being rendered twice. Even though visually people only see one version but behind the scenes the page has `$content_for_layout` loading twice on the same page. This is causing all kinds of problems to me such as duplicate forms, JavaScript elements not working correctly as a result of duplicate variables, etc. What I want to do is to modify what `$content_for_layout` does for `<div id="split-test-homepage-content-redesign">`. One option I am considering is to use JavaScript so that in the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` section I can do something in the experiment so that if a variable contains a specific boolean value, I show one version or the other. Something like this:

`if(javascriptvariable==true){` then use the following HTML for the view:

```
<div id="split-test-homepage-content-original">
    ..........
    <?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
    ..........
</div>
```

else, the Javascript will take care of not displaying the above, but this:

```
<div id="split-test-homepage-content-redesign">
    ..........
    <?php echo $content_for_layout;?>
    ..........
</div/>
```

Does the JavaScript approach make sense to you or should I do something about creating new layouts or modifying what `$content_for_layout` does? Thank you.

Comment: `$content_for_layout` contains the rendered action view template (eg. `views/posts/index.ctp`), if you want to modify what the variable holds, then you'll probably need to modify the action view template accordingly. You may get better answers if you explain _what exactly_ you want to / need to change _how exactly_, maybe provide a before/after sample.

Comment: Thank you @ndm. I explained in `UPDATE 1` of my question more specifically what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Where exactly is the (programmatic) decision being made what version should be shown to the user? If the decision is made on the server side, then you could simply change to a different layout in for example your app controller. If the decision is made in the frontend, then you should consider moving that change into the backend ;)

Comment: The decision is made in the front-end by Google Optimize, the tool for configuring the A/B testing experiments that I am using. Google Optimize does not manipulate the back-end but it can handle anything in the front-end. For that reason, it seems to me that I need to consider a front-end solution as plan A and plan B would be the back-end solution.

Comment: Ah I see, well, one way would be to use script templates, ie `<script type="text/template">` and insert the required template accordingly via JS. As long as the content is inside the template tag, it's not being interpreted as HTML, and hence won't mess up things. But note that you can't nest `<script>` tags inside of the templates.

Comment: I tried `<script type="text/template">` and it was a promising solution but I encountered a few other bugs and eventually used a much better approach to manipulate CSS classes and ids only without duplicating content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating content was definitely asking for trouble. I used a much better approach to manipulate CSS classes and ids only without duplicating content.